# How to use Next and previous Uri in Docusign using Rest Recipes

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I want to fetch 20 records/request for envelope information using Rest Recipes.

My requirement is:

When 20 records are dumped to database, I want hit another batch which will fetch me records from 21 to 40 then in the third call from 41 to 60 and so on...

I have used code below, but not getting any idea, how to get information like paging. // call the Login() API which sets the user's baseUrl and returns their accountId

```
string accountId = loginApi(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

// Set the Start Date (to limit the results returned)
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2016, 09, 15);
string fromDateStr = fromDate.ToString("o");
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2016, 09, 16);                
string toDateStr = toDate.ToString("o");

// set a filter for the envelopes we want returned using the 
// fromDate and count properties

// Here I want to use paging like functionality.
EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
{
    count = "20",// How to increase this counter for next request?
    fromDate = fromDateStr,
    toDate = toDateStr
};

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopesInformation envelopes = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is increments of 20 your real final number? That seems very low.

Comment: Andrew , that was an example, I want to configure as I want, but that was just an example, basic question is , how to get records for next range for e.g. first request will fetch 1-20, second will 21-40 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to solve?  DocuSign has a call that allows you to get a list of envelope IDs over a date/time/status range.  There wouldn't be a specific number or limit to what is returned in this scenario, but I don't understand why you want to limit it to 20 (as your example states).

Comment: Rob, I have 25K+ Envelopes, which are completed and growing day by day, I have to dump all data into another system, you are saying use status+date range for envelopes(I already tried), doesn't provide me a solution. Above statement is just an example(20 records), I want to fetch 500 or can customise number of records. I need to use envelopes details for a batch job, where first I have to dump data into another system, process this data, then next batch 500 to 1000 envelopes, I can't fetch 25K records altogether and dump into another system, since tomorrow this data will grow up to 100K

Comment: To get data from an envelope, you need to call a specific envelope.  I think the question is how do you know when to call an envelope (know it's complete). One option is to use Connect which can publish the completed event and data to a web service on your end.  With this, you can have your webservice put it in a database for a batch job or just put it directly in another system.

Comment: If you do not want to have your own web service for Connect to publish to, best practice is to run the status/date range query on a regular basis.  You can use these results to get the envelope data one by one to put in another system.

Comment: Hey Rob, I am using Docusign Connect as well, but this requirement is bit different. Anyways, if docusign has not this feature, can't do anything. Thanks for your valuable comments.